# Datepicker calls error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use that datepicker (http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/), and when I call him with my parameters from JS - he doesn't work. And when I use class `datepicker-here` - works, but I need to use with my config.

Look: https://jsfiddle.net/MyZik/3j2j7xe2/22/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
<input type="text"
       id="#datepicker1"
       name="available_time"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="Время активации">
```

to this:

```
<input type="text"
       id="datepicker1"
       name="available_time"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="Время активации">
```

what changed is the `id`. You don't need any `#` for `id` attribute in HTML.

Comment: My bad! Thank you a lot.